# How to check which thread is holding the monitor?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, jvm, jfr

I have a performance issue (in a complex Scala code using parallel collections and futures). I have used JFR to check more details and I can see the issue manifests itself as a thread waiting on a monitor object (the thread seems to be waiting in `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask#internalWait` by calling a `wait` method of the `ForkJoinTask`). I would like to know which thread holds this monitor object (and from what function / call-stack the monitor was entered). JFR shows me some kind of an address for the monitor, but I did not find a way to search / filter by this address.

[image]

Is there some view in the JMC, a plugin, or some other way how to check who and when is locking and releasing given monitor?

Comment: "jstack -l pid" should work, not sure how you can do it in JFR.

Comment: The monitor wait is not long enough for me to trigger jstack manually (usually much less than 1 second). I am able to instruct JFR to take a thread dump each second, which often hits the needed time range, however I can see only thread call-stacks in those dumps, not a list of monitors taken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, a monitor object being waited on, is not technically held by any thread. Such monitor has no "owner". In general, you can't know beforehand, which thread is in charge of calling `notify`, as it can be any thread, or no thread at all.

However, if a monitor has already been notified, there will be a JFR event containing the information about Notifier Thread. You can see it on your screenshot: the monitor was notified by `scala-execution-context-global-54` thread.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I did not understand the "Notifier Thread" entry until now. Still, given most my futures and parallel loops are running on the same same thread pool, this unfortunately does not tell me much, as almost any code can be running on that thread. I would like to learn more: can I somehow get the call-stack of the event which has notified the thread? This is what my OP was about - displaying events related to a given monitor should tell me what I needed. If this is not possible, can you think of other way?

Comment: @Suma I haven't seen this option in JFR, but you can you record `notify` calls with stack traces using [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/): run `profiler.sh -e JVM_MonitorNotify ...`

Comment: Async-profiler can also write output in JFR format, so it's possible to run both JFR and async-profiler together and then match their output by timestamps.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am afraid running async-profiler can prove difficult for me, as I am running on Windows. I will try some VM, but given my application performs 3D rendering I am not sure how easy this will be. Maybe I will be able to extract some repro without any rendering, that would make things easier.